# Retrieve condition coverage infomation with SonarQube Web API

Tags: sonarqube

I am searching for a possibility to retrieve the conditions to cover from SonarQube Web API.

After reading documentation I found out the metrics for condition coverage & and uncovered conditions, which in most cases is sufficient to calculate the conditions in total. But, if you have 100% condition coverage you cannot calculate it any more.

I found various suggestions but the all result in errors calling the API.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: Any information about the error you get?

Comment: The error I get is a REST response, that the metric I want to access is not know by the API.